# strawberry and fig vincotto

Tags: wine

I have one strawberry and one fig vincotto (bottle). What can I do with it ? Am having trouble finding recipes to use it in, other than fruit/icecream/salad related. I prefer a recipe with only a few ingredients, so the vincotto remains primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a wonderful recipe that originally uses Red Vermouth as it's main flavour. I daresay it would go very well with a fig vincotto. If you do make it, let me know how it works out in a comment.

My grandmother originally made this with veal escalopes. My mother makes it with chicken breast pieces. Since I'm basically a buddhist monk food-wise, I make it with tofu. Probably wouldn't work for really red meat though.

Anyway, cut the meat/tofu into bite size chunks, and shake them in a bag with flour seasoned with salt and pepper and some ground mace (nutmeg is just as good here).

Put some olive oil and a whole diced white onion in a skillet and start the fire on low. Stir and cook slowly to let the onion get all dark and sweet. Then add some minced garlic, the vincotto and a teaspoon or two of tomato paste.

Now throw in the floured meat/tofu bits and sautee until done.
The whole things takes half an hour, most of which is the onions, which need the time.

Comment: Sounds like something to try.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any recipe that uses a (sweet / balsamic) vinegar as a sauce base could also use fig vincotto instead. Plenty of meat dishes, for instance.

Comment: Okay. So instead of using vinegar and sweeteners, I could use vincotto. So, in my case I'd probably use it on something wild (deer, rabbit).

Comment: I'd have a go at such a dish, yessir.